# Streaming Transformation in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration application which polls from a database, marshalls into XML, and then sends that XML as a message to a downstream system. The application works, but the issue we face is that some of the result sets can be massive. In such cases, it appears Spring Integration cannot handle the transformation because the result set is too big to handle in memory. I do not see a Stax marshaller in Spring Integration, as there is say in Spring Batch. That actually makes sense, because messaging usually means working with many small messages and not large files.

One option we have is to develop a Spring Batch application instead.

Is there a design we could adopt for Spring Integration to handle this? Does Spring Integration have any notion of streaming? For instance, would it be possible to read the result set in chunks, transform each piece, and each piece as a separate message which is part of a set? Or is Spring Batch just a better fit?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max-rows-per-poll` to limit the size of each result set.

If that's not practical then you can use a combination of Spring Batch and Spring Integration - have the batch `ItemWriter` send the chunks into a Spring Integration flow via a `<gateway/>`.

Comment: 1. As I just want to send to a downstream system, why would SI be necessary here- could I not just use a SB JmsItemWriter? 2. Would a possible SI solution be to poll from the DB to a persistent queue, and have an aggregator read from that, thus spliting up the transformation?

Comment: 1. I assumed you were doing more than just dumping to JMS; if that's all you're doing then batch is probably best for large data sets. 2. Yes but, again, it depends on what you're doing with the data as to whether it's worth it.